# How to AutoFilter Excel by RGB cell color with win32com in Python

Tags: python, win32com, autofilter

Let me start by saying that I am not a very skilled programmer, so please keep your answers as simple as possible so I have a chance to understand :-)

I am trying to figure out how to use win32com to open Excel and AutoFilter a column based on cell background colour.
The VBA code for what I want to do is this:

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$613").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, _
        153, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

I can make it work by using a VBA color constant value for yellow

```
ws.Range("B:B").AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=65535, Operator=8)
```

But I need to be able to filter by more colours than just the VBA color constant colors.

My code so far is:

```
from win32com.client import constants as c 

excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("path\to\file\filename.xlsm", False, True) 
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws_current.Range('B:B').AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=65535, Operator=c.xlFilterCellColor)
```

This works to filter by the color yellow, but I need to be able to replace the Criteria1 Field with an RGB value.

Using this code:

```
ws_current.Range('B:B').AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=RGB(255,255,0), Operator=c.xlFilterCellColor)
```

results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-64-809552ca6582>", line 1, in <module>
    ws_current.Range('B:B').AutoFilter(Field=1, Criteria1=RGB(255,255,0), Operator=c.xlFilterCellColor)
NameError: name 'RGB' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for any insights

Comment: What is `RBG`, and where is it defined?

Comment: The VBA code snippet that I included came from me recording a macro. I don't know where in VBA `RGB` is defined, or how I would use it with win32com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RGB macro comes from the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb) and is implemented in Python [by pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__RGB_meth.html).

In Python, if you have installed `pywin32` (which you will have if you are using `win32com`), you can just write:

```
from win32api import RGB

n = RGB(255,255,0)
print(n)
```

which yields `65535`.

So if the OP simply adds the line `from win32api import RGB` the original code should work.

Comment: I have tested this with my code and it works. Thank you very much!